# Erro 04018 ao tentar fazer o build de um projeto de banco de dados SQL

Tags: visual-studio-2013, team-foundation-server, team-build

Criei o meu projeto de banco de dados no **Visual Studio 2013** apontando para uma base existente, coloco um novo build para execução no TFS e acontece o seguinte erro:

```
Error 04018: The “SqlBuildTask” task failed unexpectedly
```

Não fiz nenhuma alteração no *build template*, mas testei com outro projeto de base de dados e o erro não aconteceu.

Answer (score 2):

É um *bug* do produto! Para resolvê-lo é só fazer a atualização, se estiver com a atualização re-instale.

1. O download está nessa [**página**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/hh297027)(Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools).
2. Se a sua *build machine* não tem acesso a internet, utilize o comando:

   ```
   SSDTUpdate.exe /layout SSDTUpdate
   ```

Ele fará o download para a pasta `SSDTUpdate` dos arquivos necessários para uma instalação desconectada.